# install packages in r without devtools or install.package()

Tags: r, package, devtools

when I try to install some packages via `devtools`, I get the message that I dont have `devtools` installed (and this is true). But when I try them to install `devtools`, i get:

`Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`

I cant find a way to deal with this properly. Anyone?

Comment: a. Update R, that's old. b. Make sure you have a working CRAN mirror selected. c. That error usually means "check your spelling", though it looks fine here.

Comment: @alistaire already made all that ):

Comment: changed to a random CRAN mirror and it worked. but now "installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status"

Comment: non-zero exit status just means it was not able to install but you can extract it and run it.

Comment: @zx8754 i had checked that question.

Comment: @EVX I managed to deal with that already.

Comment: thanks to everyone, problem solved. this started with me trying to get "catterplots" (https://github.com/Gibbsdavidl/CatterPlots) :)